# Why is Ansible not assigning the value from `stdout` and instead only the registered variable name?

Tags: ansible

This seems like a simple thing and I have done it many times before, but I started to notice some issues lately.  Maybe I am just missing something dumb.

I have some pretty simply plays:

```
- name: Test register
  ansible.builtin.shell: echo something
  register: test_value

- name: Output test value
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ test_value }}"
```

The results of these plays are:

```
TASK [foo/bar : Test register] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_host] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo something", "delta": "0:00:00.002040", "end": "2023-05-24 05:49:06.107897", "msg": "", "rc": 0, "start": "2023-05-24 05:49:06.105857", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "something", "stdout_lines": ["something"]}

TASK [foo/bar : Output test value] ***************************************************************************
ok: [test_host] => {
"msg": "test_value"
}
```

Ansible version:

```
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.13 (main, Nov  9 2022, 13:16:24) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Why is it that I am only getting the registered variable name and not actually the `stdout` contents?  This seems to also be inconsistent for me as well.

Comment: Since this isn't reproducible, what is an `ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: test_value` showing? Also I have the feeling the the description of the case is slightly misleading, at least for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#return-values)

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable ...*

and [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)

> *Registered variables may be simple variables, list variables, dictionary variables, or complex nested data structures. The documentation for each module includes a RETURN section describing the return values for that module.*

in your case [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets - Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-values).

> *I am only getting the registered variable name and not actually the `stdout` contents?*

As you can see from your output

```json
"stdout": "something", "stdout_lines": ["something"]
```

you should get it via

```yaml
- name: Output test value
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: test_value

- name: Output test value
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: test_value.stdout
```

---

For me it is not possible to produce a behavior where a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: "echo something"
    register: TEST

  - debug:
      var: TEST

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ TEST }}"
```

would just `"msg": "TEST"` instead of the expected

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  TEST:
    changed: true
    cmd: echo something
    delta: '0:00:00.012925'
    end: '2023-05-24 12:00:00.856922'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-05-24 12:00:00.843997'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: something
    stdout_lines:
    - something

TASK [debug] **************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    changed: true
    cmd: echo something
    delta: '0:00:00.012925'
    end: '2023-05-24 12:00:00.856922'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-05-24 12:00:00.843997'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: something
    stdout_lines:
    - something
```

---

> *Why is it that I am only getting the ... variable name and not actually the ... contents?*

I am able to produce your behavior via [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) and calling a minimal example playbook with [`--extra-vars`](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/extra-variables-ansible-playbook) to always win precedence

> *In general, Ansible gives precedence to variables that were defined more recently, more actively, and with more explicit scope.*

in your case

```sh
ansible-playbook debug.yml --extra-vars="test_value=test_value"
```

or in my case

```sh
ansible-playbook debug.yml --extra-vars="TEST=TEST"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test_value
```

or

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: TEST
```

but that would mean the description of your case is missing important information or is misleading.

Whatever, still, **the content of the registered variable is displayed. It might look like the variable name but it is the content which is "the same as" the variable name**.

If that is really the case you may need to search for such occurrences within your source code, in example `~/test$ grep -Rn test_value .`

Comment: Thank you, you are indeed correct.  I in fact forgot to add in the .stdout to my little test plays.  So my inconsistencies are not actually a result of this, but something entirely different.  I made myself a red herring and will mark answered for this.